# How to write Firebase query to filter out data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I wanted to write a query so as to filter the data using an edittext, the code below does work but bring all of the unwanted searched data. Can you please help me? The JSON object is as follows: The data I wanted to filter out is the username

[image: firebase json object]

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView searchList;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
FirebaseListAdapter<SearchDetails> listAdapter;
String search;
EditText editTextSearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    searchList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSearch);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Search Users");

    editTextSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);


    editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            search = editTextSearch.getText().toString();
            if (search.equals("")){
                searchList.setAdapter(null);
            }else{
                searchList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            }
        }
    });

    Query query = databaseReference.startAt(search).endAt(search+"~").limitToFirst(10);
    listAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<SearchDetails>(
            this,
            SearchDetails.class,
            R.layout.search_layout,
            query
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, SearchDetails model, int position) {
            TextView username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername);
            username.setText(model.getUsername());
            TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            name.setText(model.getName());
        }
    };

}
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify, what data do you want to get ? The question is not very clear to me.

Comment: I would like to filter out only the username

Comment: Hey @Jama I Added an answer for you below, let me know if this helps and/or you'd like to know something more.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this problem we need to understand a few things about Firebase, that a lot of developers might overlook.

- It is a NoSQL based Data Storage, so you have to structure your data accordingly.
- Firebase allows you to nest nodes into your data structure for up to 32 levels deep, *and this can be easily abused*.

The problem that I think you have at hand is to "have an `EditText` that allows user to search for **usernames** of your **users**.

How I would suggest you to tackle this is by flattening the structure of your data like so

[image]
You can have objects inside `usernames` array. Each object's key is the `username` and the value is another object with an `empty-key : ""` like so.

And you can then have another array of `users` where again the keys are `usernames` and rest of the data lives as an object under it.

Now you can easily run your Filter Query on `usernames` without worrying about the overhead of fetching unnecessary data in that query.

And once you know which `username` was selected, you can query `users` to fetch that exact `user` from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("username").startAt(search).endAt(search+"~").limitToFirst(10);

Comment: I am sorry but it did not work, it brought all of the unwanted data